# Renaming file name on upload, JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have 4 input tags to upload 4 different files,

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="upload" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: absolute; right: -5%; top: 2%;">
Left File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /><br><br>
Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /><br><br>
Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /><br><br>
Geco File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile4" id="fileChooser4" /><br><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload</button>
</form>
```

Now on my Servlet.java side I want to rename the file which is being uploaded.

How do I do that? Using commons up loader.

PS: I've tried to get the name of the id of the input tag so that I can create an if loop and assign fileName name as required,

```
String my = request.getParameter("dataFile1");
System.out.println(my);
```

This print's null.

Comment: Yes, I did try that, it works well but I want to rename the file while being uploaded.

Comment: Yep, done. Check now, suggest edits if any

Comment: Another update to my answer, to make it clearer.

Comment: Hello Please tell me you are on Servlet 3.0 ? or apache commons ? i mean how you handle the uploaded file in the Servlet ?

Comment: Hey amro I am on apache commons.

Comment: Hey paul, I'm checking it will let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you have to do is the following :

1st - parse the request to get a list of FileItem like the following :

```
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

2nd - process the uploaded items like the following :

```
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {  
  FileItem item = iter.next();   
 if (item.isFormField()) {      
  processFormField(item);   
 } else if (!item.isFormField()) { 
 // Process a file upload
    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();  
  String fileName = item.getName();   
 String contentType = item.getContentType(); 
   boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();  
  long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();

//here you change the name of the uploaded file and then write it 

    File uploadedFile = new File(dir , "fileName");   
 item.write(uploadedFile);


  }
}
```

and please check the documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) in the section Processing the uploaded items .

and give me some feedback

Hope That Helps .

Answer (score 1):

To figure out which file is which, use the [FileItem](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) that you get from [ServletFileUpload#parseRequest](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29), you can call the [getFieldName](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getFieldName%28%29) method to get the value of the **name** attribute from the JSP snippet above.

To save the file with a particular name, create a [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object with the correct name and call [FileItem#write](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#write%28java.io.File%29) with that object.

This code is untested but should give you a place to start.

```
List items = upload.parseRequest(httpRequest);
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
File outputDir = getOutputDir();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
  String origName = item.getFieldName();
  if ("dataFile1".equals(origName) {
    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, "firstFile.txt"); // This bit is doing the renaming
    item.write(outputFile);
  } // ... else all the other inputs get handled ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the old-fashioned iterators and whathaveyou.  I'm working straight off the javadocs.. no IDE here to help me :(

Comment: The important part is that it works. A sample is just to illustrate the general concept, not writing the most perfectly elegant code :)